# What is a Double Perfect?

Tags: achievements, runner2

I recently noticed an achievement in *Runner2* called "Double Perfectionist". The text says I need to:

> Get two Double Perfects in Each World

Problem is, I have no idea what a Double Perfect is, let alone how to get one.

**What is a Double Perfect, and how do I get one?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A double perfect is getting a perfect twice in the other game dificulties. That is, **Rather Easy**, **Just Right**, and **Rather Hard**.

To start off, getting a perfect means getting all the gold bars within a level AS well as getting all the score multipliers (mode UPs).

Getting a perfect on "Just Right and Rather Hard" or "Just Right and Rather Easy", or "Rather Easy and Rather Hard" **in 2 levels** of each world will get you your achievement.

Answer (score 11):

As you may or may not already be aware, Runner 2 has three separate difficulties: **Rather Easy**, **Just Right**, and **Quite Hard**. Unlike in Bit.Trip Runner, where the difficulties merely altered the speed / collection requirements, the various difficulty levels in Runner 2 adjust the level itself, by adding enemies.

The other half of explaining this involves a brief explanation of the **Perfect** System itself  - Collect all the gold and mode+ on the level (regardless of checkpoints, loops, or alternate paths), and you will score a perfect! If you reach the bonus cannon after crossing the finish line, you have gotten a perfect on the level. (Going on to then score a bullseye earns you a Perfect+, which is also tracked, but irrelevant to this question).

So a **Double Perfect** is earned when you have earned a Perfect on two of a level's difficulties, and a **Triple Perfect** when you have perfect!'d all three. Perfect!s are marked on the world map's levels as you achieve them, appearing as a colored exclamation point - Yellow ! for Quite Easy, Blue! for Just Right, and a Purple! for Rather Hard.

This means, to get the achievement you quote, you would have to beat 10 levels (2 in each world) a minimum of 2 times each (in two of the three difficulties).

Comment: Did you mean a minimum of 2 times each?  It seems like 3 times each would be for a Triple Perfect, right?

Comment: @EBongo The achievement itself requires 2 double perfects per world, and then 3 triple perfects per world.

Comment: > ... Pink ! for Just Right, and a Red ! for Rather Hard.

Comment: On the WiiU version, I have a Blue "!" for Just Right, and Purple "!" for Rather Hard.  These colors correspond to the bullseye icon (with the upper-right corner of the "!" actually touching the same-colored ring of the bullseye).

Comment: @not-just-yeti Thanks, fixed. I am not sure why I listed the wrong colors.

Comment: "Double Perfectionist" only requires "a minimum of 2 times each" not 3. You don't need triple perfects for "Double Perfectionist" which this question is about.