# What do I get for skipping the checkpoint?

Tags: runner2

After playing for a while, I figured out that you have a choice to trigger the checkpoint, or jump it (previously I was jumping it every time).  The game tells you that you can skip it "*for a greater challenge*", and I see that I get some points at the end of the level for doing so.

I've already found that there is a Perfect and Perfection+ outcome for each level, and I've read about "[Double Perfections](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107118/what-is-a-double-perfect)" and "Triple Perfections" in other questions - so I'm curious if there is any other "collectible/challenge" reason to skip the checkpoints.  By the time I've done a few passes through the game I don't want to have to do it all again if there is some special outcome for skipping them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're aiming for high scores, skip the checkpoint.

If you want a challenge, skip the checkpoint.

If you want to prove you're a *true* badass, skip the checkpoint.

The checkpoint awards 50,000 points if you skip it.  This can be a deciding factor separating you from other players going for high scores.

Comment: Also, the first time you do it, you earn the "A New Challenger"
(Checkpoints!? Who Needs 'Em!?) achievement.